# JavaScript().Serializer() gets [object, object]

Tags: c#, javascript, serialization, javascriptserializer

I can am trying to serialize some code from C# into JavaScript so I can use it in the client side. However when I do this it fetches `[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]`, however if I pass a normal string say `"Hello"`, it works fine, so the serialize doesn't seem to be the problem.

So my C# code looks like:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<YearMonthGrid> ymgs = new List<YearMonthGrid>();
    ymgs = DAL.GetYearMonthGrid("value");


    var m = from c in ymgs where c.Month == 7 select c;

    v1 = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(m);
}
```

and my JS code looks like:

```
var d1 = <%=this.v1%>;
document.write(d1);
```

The class `YearMonthGrid` has three properties which I use in the list:

- Name (String)
- Quantity (int)
- Month (int)

When I debug it, my value `v1` contains the string I want to return, however when I try to get it, it just shows me `Object` over and over. Any ideas to why this is?

Comment: `[object Object]` is the default string representation of an object. So, if you convert an array of a objects `d1` to a string, this output is to be expected. If you just want to inspect the value, use `console.log`. Otherwise, access the properties of the objects which you want to work with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When converting an object to a string (i.e. writing it out to a page) then it will write out `[object Object]` instead of the contents of the object. Instead, try doing something like this:

```
var d1 = <%=this.v1%>;
for (var i = 0; i < d1.length; i++) {
    var yearMonthGrid = d1[i];
    document.write(yearMonthGrid.Name + '<br />');
    document.write(yearMonthGrid.Quantity + '<br />');
    document.write(yearMonthGrid.Month + '<br />');
}
```

If you're running this in Firefox or Chrome (I haven't tried in newer versions of other browsers) then you could also do this to see the contents of each object:

```
var d1 = <%=this.v1%>;
for (var i = 0; i < d1.length; i++) {
    console.log(d1[i]);
}
```

Just make sure you have your JavaScript console open.

Comment: Right... So it was passing the data correctly, it's just not viewable writing it straight from the variable. I see now, thanks.